# Visual Basic - picturebox name variable increment

Tags: vba, variables, picturebox

Is there a way to set the image from one PictureBox object to another?  For example:

```
pictureboxA1.image = pictureboxB1.image
pictureboxA2.image = pictureboxB2.image
pictureboxA3.image = pictureboxB3.image
```

I did a similar thing with TextBox controls, but this code isn't working for me:

```
For i = 0 To 2
  Me.Controls("picturebox" + "A" & i + 1).image = Me.Controls("picturebox" + "B" & i + 1).image
Next i
```

When I run this, I get an error stating `.image is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'`.

---

i know that is pictureboxA1.image = pictureboxB1.image.

but if i try like this

```
For i = 0 To 2
  Me.Controls("picturebox" + "A" & i + 1).image = Me.Controls("picturebox" + "B" & i + 1).image
Next i
```

it says that image is not a member of controls.
because i have to do this pictureboxA1.image = pictureboxB1.image, 21 times.

like 
pictureboxA1, pictureboxA2, ... 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 until 21.

and if i do it like this

```
pictureboxA1.image = pictureboxB1.image
```

i have to right the code 21 times and if i do it with for its just one time xD.

and i tryed .picture it says the same thing

Comment: You've posted a comment as an answer again.  Please stop doing that.  I realize now the problem is that you need to cast the control as a PictureBox.

Comment: You've done it again :).  I flagged your "answers" so hopefully they'll be gone soon.  It sounds like my answer solved your question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I should have seen this sooner.  You need to set the control to a PictureBox in order for it to recognize the property.  I think.  Something like this might work.  I don't have access to a PictureBox control, so it's a guess:

```
Dim pic as PictureBox

For i = 0 To 2
  set pic = Me.Controls("picturebox" + "A" & i + 1)
  pic.image = Me.Controls("picturebox" + "B" & i + 1).image
Next i
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, post a comment below this one, or edit your post.